# Die Verwendung von nicht

Tags: grammar, word-order, negation

Es fällt vielen Anfängern wie mir schwer, zu bestimmen, auf welchen Platz sie das *nicht* setzen sollen. Gibt es irgendwelche Wege, um zu wissen, wie man das macht? Alles, was ich weiß, ist, dass es dem Wenfall folgt:

> z.B. Ich habe Skype nicht.

Und dass es vor Präpositionen steht:

> z.B. Ich spreche nicht mit dir, sondern mit ihr.

Comment: "`Ich habe Skype nicht`" klingt ungewöhnlich, ich möchte sogar sagen, das ist falsch. Eher so: `Skype habe ich nicht.` (Aber umgangssprachlich wäre `Ich habe kein Skype` korrekt)

Comment: `Ich habe Skype nicht` is grammatikalisch korrect, wenn auch ungewöhnlich. `Ich habe kein Skype` ist sicherlich besser, nicht nur *umgangssprachlich*.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem isn't so much in the placement of *nicht* as in the effect that German's V2 (verb second) word order has on it. Normally, *nicht* precedes whatever it is negating, just like in English.

However, if *nicht* negates a verb, then it is part of the verb group of the sentence. V2 means that the conjugated verb, and only the conjugated verb, comes in second position and the remainder of the verb group follows at the end:

1. Ich habe es gesehen. (Infinitive of verb group: *gesehen haben*. Conjugated verb: *habe*. Remainder of verb group at end of sentence: *gesehen*.)
2. Ich habe es nicht gesehen. (Infinitive of verb group: *nicht gesehen haben*. Conjugated verb: *habe*. Remainder of verb group at end of sentence: *nicht gesehen*.)
3. Ich habe es. (Infinitive of verb group: *haben*. Conjugated verb: *habe*. Remainder of verb group at end of sentence: nothing.)
4. Ich habe es nicht. (Infinitive of verb group: *nicht haben*. Conjugated verb: *habe*. Remainder of verb group at end of sentence: *nicht*.)

English also was once a V2 language, or at least similar to one. (V2 is an intermediate step between SOV, the original Germanic word order, and 'modern' SVO word order.) You can still see traces in the way English negates auxiliaries and *do*, and you can see it in the way Early Modern English ('Shakespeare English') did negations without *do* support. In these cases, *not* always comes *after* the conjugated verb it negates, even though in general it comes before its referent, even if that's an infinitive:

1. I have seen it.
2. I have not seen it.
3. I have it.
4. I have it not.

Even though today we may be inclined to interpret 2 by bracketing "I have (not seen) it", what really happened is that the earlier word order "I have it not seen", which was just like in German, was simplified only part of the way by moving *it* to the end, but without moving *not* into its logical position in front of *have*. 4 is archaic but should still sound somewhat familiar. The modern colloquial and somewhat questionable construction *I haven't it* as well as the mainstream solutions to the problem of negating *have* -- *I do not have it* and *I haven't got it* - all have the same structure as 2.

To recap the last part, English negates verbs as follows:

- infinite verb forms, i.e. infinitives, participles and gerunds, are negated by prepending *not*: *to not eat / not to eat*, *not eaten*, *not eating*;
- conjugated verb forms are negated by *not* immediately following the verb

  - but since this is no longer a natural consequence of (V2) word order but rather an apparently arbitrary rule, it has become restricted to auxiliaries and *do*; arbitrary verbs are now negated by adding *do* so it can get the negation; overall it feels as if full verbs were negated by putting a 'negative' auxiliary in front.

Comment: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/1048/1487

Comment: Oh, da hab ich wohl mal wieder die Sprache gewechselt, ohne es zu merken. War keine Absicht.